# Javascript output shows NaN when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, nan

Hello I have written some code so that the user would input a degrees centigrade value, and have the program convert to degrees fahrenheit. I'm not sure why the output shows NaN when I try it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var degFahren;
    var degCent;
    function input_onchange(degCent) {
      degFahren = parseInt((9 / 5) * degCent + 32);
      document.form1.output.value = degFahren;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" name="form1" method="post">
        <h3>Type any degrees centigrade and convert it to Fahrenheit.</h3>
        <p>
          Degrees Centigrade:
          <input type="text" name="input" onchange="input_onchange()">
        </p>
        <p>
          Degrees Fahrenheit:
          <input type="text" name="output" readonly="readonly">
        </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the future, you can find the answer yourself really easily: Use the fully-featured debugger built into your browser to set a breakpoint on the first statement in your function, then use it to look at the variables, etc. There are links to details about the various debuggers built into browsers in [the JavaScript tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are not passing the value to your `input_onchange` method. Change your `onchange` attribute like so;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var degFahren;
    var degCent;
    function input_onchange(degCent) {
      degFahren = parseInt((9 / 5) * degCent + 32);
      document.form1.output.value = degFahren;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" name="form1" method="post">
        <h3>Type any degrees centigrade and convert it to Fahrenheit.</h3>
        <p>
          Degrees Centigrade:
          <input type="text" name="input" onchange="input_onchange(this.value)">
        </p>
        <p>
          Degrees Fahrenheit:
          <input type="text" name="output" readonly="readonly">
        </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

... here, `this` refers to the element itself (the `input`).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the input field value to the function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var degFahren;
    var degCent;
    function input_onchange(degCent) {
      degFahren = parseInt((9 / 5) * degCent + 32);
      document.form1.output.value = degFahren;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" name="form1" method="post">
        <h3>Type any degrees centigrade and convert it to Fahrenheit.</h3>
        <p>
          Degrees Centigrade:
          <input type="text" name="input" onchange="input_onchange(this.value)">
        </p>
        <p>
          Degrees Fahrenheit:
          <input type="text" name="output" readonly="readonly">
        </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var degFahren;
    var degCent;
    function input_onchange(degCent) {
      degFahren = parseInt((9 / 5) * degCent + 32);
      console.log(degFahren);
      document.form1.output.value = degFahren;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" name="form1" method="post">
        <h3>Type any degrees centigrade and convert it to Fahrenheit.</h3>
        <p>
          Degrees Centigrade:
          <input type="text" name="input" onchange="input_onchange(this.value)">
        </p>
        <p>
          Degrees Fahrenheit:
          <input type="text" name="output" readonly="readonly">
        </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem was you were not passing any parameter to `input_onchange()` method

Answer (score -1):

You have requested a parameter in your function, but you didnt pass it a value.
I adjusted your code a bit... it should work fine now :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var degFahren;
    var degCent;
    function input_onchange() {
      var degCent = document.getElementById("input-centigrade").value;
      degFahren = parseInt((9 / 5) * degCent + 32);
      document.form1.output.value = degFahren;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" name="form1" method="post">
        <h3>Type any degrees centigrade and convert it to Fahrenheit.</h3>
        <p>
          Degrees Centigrade:
          <input type="text" name="input" id="input-centigrade" onchange="input_onchange()">
        </p>
        <p>
          Degrees Fahrenheit:
          <input type="text" name="output" readonly="readonly">
        </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```